# How to trigger mongoose default value when attribute is null

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

In my schema, I defined a default value for an attribute :

```
const patientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    lastName: {type : String, required: true},
    firstName: {type : String, required: true},
    phone: String,
    mobile: String,
    email: String,
    subscriptionDate: {type : Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

I would like it to be used when the passed value is null. I know it only works if its undefined but I imagine that there is a clean workaround for this.

For now I'm doing this but I have to do it for both creation and update and I feel it's dirty :

```
const patient = new Patient({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        mobile: req.body.mobile,
        email: req.body.email,
        subscriptionDate: req.body.subscriptionDate ? req.body.subscriptionDate : undefined,
        gender: req.body.gender,
        birthDate: req.body.birthDate,
        nbChildren: req.body.nbChildren,
        job: req.body.job,
        address: req.body.address
    });
    patient.save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'Handling POST requests to /patients',
                createdPatient: patient
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            const error = new Error(err);
            next(error);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose default values work only if your document object keys do not have those fields defined. `[empty,null]` are valid values. As you are handling at object creation time that is the one way I can see here i.e. either you can assign `undefined` or else you can delete that property from an object.

Comment: Humm, ok. I guess I'll stick to my dirty workaround. Many thanks